# Why null chars added in array?

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, undefined-behavior

I have an array which keeps **chars** of a **string** and want to find its **suffixes**. If i add 7 chars in the array the total number of chars should be 7*8/2 = 28. So the suffix_array limit should be 28. When i tried to create suffix array i noticed that array has null chars ass well. So my output is wrong. **What is the reason of this?**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static char *suffix;

int main()
{
    char s[7] = {'c','o','n','n','e','c','t'};
    suffix = (char*) malloc(sizeof (char)*28);
    int j;
    static int k=0;
    j=k;
    for(int i=0; i<28; i++) {
        suffix[i] = s[j];
        printf("%c ", suffix[i]);
        if(j<7) {
            j++;
        }
        else {
            k++;
            j=k;
        }
            
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

```
Output:

c o n n e c t  o n n e c t  n n e c t  n e c t  e c
```

Comment: Where do you output anything?

Comment: @Gerhardh 1+2+...+n = n(n+1)/2

Comment: Every 7 iterations of your loop, you have `j == 7`, and `s[7]` is out of bounds (zero indexed arrays, remember?)

Comment: @Gerhardh the suffix of array should be like connect onnect nnect ... So the number of chars calculation is 7+6+... It equals to 7*8/2

Comment: @arne: output is from `printf("%c ", suffix[i]);`

Comment: Do you have to store the concatenated suffixes at all? You only print each character immediately. You could just print the original string but start from index 0, 1, 2, ... 6. Or if you need to store them, you could use `strcat`

Comment: @NateEldredge yeah you r right. Thats why debugging is so important feature. I was getting the input of string from coomand line within a text file in my main program. I dont know how can i debug my program in this situation.

Comment: Note that AddressSanitizer and UBSan both catch this overrun instantly: https://godbolt.org/z/fzPMfqx4a

Comment: @Ahmeett_ Re "*I dont know how can i debug my program in this situation*", When learning, it's sometimes best to take out a sheet of paper, and create a column for each variable. Walk through the program yourself. But, you could use an IDE to do the same. The questions you're trying to answer is: Where did the actual behaviour deviate from the expected behaviour? You could work backwards. What values do my variable have when I get the error? (`suffix[i]` is junk). Why? `s[j]` is junk. Why? `j==7`, which is beyond the end of the array. Why? `if (j<7) { j++; }` is wrong.

Comment: Note that `-fsanitize=address` would shortcut the process, taking you straight to "j is beyond the end of the array".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You end up with j==7 (`if (j<7) { j++; }`), which is beyond the end of `s`.

Replace

```c
if(j<7) {
    j++;
}
else {
    k++;
    j=k;
}
```

with

```c
j++;
if(j==7) {
    k++;
    j=k;
}
```

Tips:

- Hardcoding 7 and 28 is a bad idea (including the way Vlad did it). It would be best to use
  `char s[] = {...}; size_t n = sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0]);` (if array)
  `const char *s = "connect"; size_t n = strlen(s);` (if string)
- You don't really use `suffix`. But if you wanted to build a string in `suffix`, make sure to allocate one more char for the trailing NUL and to add the trailing NUL!

Answer (score 1):

The for loop invokes undefined behavior even in its first iteration

```
for(int i=0; i<28; i++) {
    suffix[i] = s[j];
    printf("%c ", suffix[i]);
    if(j<7) {
        j++;
    }
    //...
```

When `j` is equal to `6` the it is increased

```
    if(j<7) {
        j++;
    }
```

So `j` becomes equal to `7` and this value is used in the next iteration of the loop in the assignment statement

```
    suffix[i] = s[j];
```

As a result there is an access to the memory past the last element of the array `s` because the valid range of indices for this array is `[0, 7 )`.

Pay attention to that there is no great sense to declare the variable suffix in the file scope and to make local variables static.

Your program could be simplified at least the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    enum { N = 7, M = ( N * ( N + 1 ) ) / 2 };

    const char s[N] = { 'c','o','n','n','e','c','t' };
    char *suffix = malloc( sizeof( char ) * M );

    for ( size_t i = 0, k = 0, j = k; i < M; i++ ) 
    {
        suffix[i] = s[j++];
        printf("%c ", suffix[i]);

        if ( j == N ) j = ++k;
    }

    free( suffix );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
c o n n e c t o n n e c t n n e c t n e c t e c t c t t
```

Pay attention to that you should always free dynamically allocated arrays when they are not required any more.

Actually in this program there is no need to allocate the result array dynamically. You could just write

```
char suffix[M];
```